Magento 2 : How to click SYSTEM button on the dashboard using Python's Selenium
After clicking on the SYSTEM button in the title, I want to click on the Import button to transition to the page, but I get an error because I can't find the element.
How do I resolve the error?
The corresponding code in Python is shown below.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
magento_url = "*************"
driver.get(magento_url)

loginID_2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "username")
loginPass_2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "login")

loginID_2.send_keys("*******")
loginPass_2.send_keys("********")

signin_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-form"]/fieldset/div[3]/div[1]/button') 
signin_btn.click()

system_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@id='menu-magento-backend-system']")))
system_btn.click()

import_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-magento-backend-system"]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a'))) 
import_btn.click()

The error details are presented below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\204158\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5616\1284163066.py", line 62, in <module>
import_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-magento-backend-system"]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a')))
File "C:\Users\204158\AppData\Local\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

In some cases, the following errors occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\204158\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21016\2154041949.py", line 63, in <module>
import_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="menu-magento-backend-system"]/div/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a')))
File "C:\Users\204158\AppData\Local\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Can you explain requirement in some more details.

Thanks for your comment.
To explain why I want to click the SYSTEM button, it is to automatically upload the CSV file (Stock Sources).
Is my explanation detailed enough?

For the automatically/periodically things, you can use magento cron system.

I don't have permission to run magento cron sytem.
